# Submit data from a submit event in Oracle Jet

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, oracle-jet

I am trying to `POST` data from submit event. The request to the REST service itself is working. The REST service has two parameters `user` and `password`.
I print-out the two parameters so I know my view model contains the data.
How can I add the parameters to the request, the values are empty on the server-side?

PS. Oracle Jet is build on KnouckoutJS, JQuery and some other JS libs.

login.js

```
function homeContentViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.user = ko.observable("Super");
    self.password = ko.observable("Sectret");
    self.userInput = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        return this.user() + " " + this.password();
    }, this);

    self.submitBt = function (data, event) {
        alert(self.user() +" - " +self.password());
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/myservice/rest/application/loginUser",
            data: {user: self.user(), password: self.password()},
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                var x = data;

            }
        });
        return true;
    }
}
```

login.html

```
<label for="text-input">User:</label>
    <input id="text-input" type="text"
           data-bind="ojComponent: {component: 'ojInputText', value: user}"/>

<label for="text-input">Password:</label>
    <input id="text-input" type="text"
           data-bind="ojComponent: {component: 'ojInputText', value: password}"/>

    <br/>

<input id="submit" type="submit" data-bind="click: submitBt, 
        ojComponent: {component: 'ojButton', label: 'Login'}"/>
```

Comment: Debug your ajax request in chrome debugger network tab to see if you get 404, 200 or some other error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that...

> REST service has two parameters `name` and `password`.

But in your `$.ajax` call, you set data to...

```
{user: self.user(), password: self.password()}
```

I think that should be...

```
{name: self.user(), password: self.password()}
```

I can't be sure, but that mismatch might account for why it isn't working.

Also, use the browser's Network tracking to see what your request looks like.  If you don't see your values in the request, then it would explain why they aren't showing up on the server.

Comment: Thanks, everything working fine today. The name of the parameters was actually úser´and ´password´, changed the question text.